# How to generate edmx from postgresql database

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, npgsql

I have a database in postgresql and i want to generate the edmx (entity framework) using wizard in vs 2010(v4.0) in my project.

I followed all steps given in this blog 
http://fxjr.blogspot.in/2011/05/npgsql-design-time-support-preview.html but i can't find data provider for postgresql while generating the edmx.

I have seen http://ud-csharp.blogspot.in/2010/02/entity-framework-con-postgresql.html also but didn't get any success.

Answer (score 0):

After dealing with similar issues with Npgsql generating Entity objects, I started looking at commercial options.

I've had great luck with Devart's dotConnect for PostgreSQL Pro.  The documentation is good, 1 year support is included, and they tend to add compatibility with new features & Visual Studio versions sooner than Npgsql.

http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/

Answer (score 0):

The `NpgsqlDdexProvider` works with EntityFramework 5 and 6. I have successfully generated models from Postgres using Visual Studio 2015.

See http://www.npgsql.org/doc/ddex.html